# Getting error "Changing property 'osDisk.name' is not allowed." with Azure Powershell Script

Tags: azure, powershell-3.0, azure-virtual-machine

I'm trying to move an existing Azure VM with a Managed Disk into an existing Availability Set. However, when I apply the command:

```
New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rg -Location $OriginalVM.Location -VM $NewVM -DisableBginfoExtension
```

I get the following error:

> New-AzureRmVM : Changing property 'osDisk.name' is not allowed.
>   ErrorCode: PropertyChangeNotAllowed
>   ErrorMessage: Changing property 'osDisk.name' is not allowed.
>   StatusCode: 409
>   ReasonPhrase: Conflict
>   OperationID : c179070b-e189-4025-84b0-87ba748f5844
>   At line:2 char:5
>   +     New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rg -Location $OriginalVM.Locati ...
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmVM], ComputeCloudException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.NewAzureVMCommand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Azure ,once the disk is attached to the VM ,there is no way to change the name of the disk. The OS disk will get the name of the VM as provided by you during the creation of the VM. You can refer to [**this link**](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c8ee9337-0e7e-40b0-a4c5-c212bb169f0e/changing-os-disk-name-and-network-interface-card-name?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows) to find more details.

I did a test and reproduced the same error as yours. Because I changed the OS disk name with `Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk`. Then I deleted the cmdlet which changed the OS disk’s name and succeed.

You can refer to create the vm without changing the OS disk name like the following cmdlet:

```
$VirtualMachine = Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $VirtualMachine -ManagedDiskId $disk.Id -CreateOption Attach -Windows
```

The whole powershell cmdlet I used :

```
#Provide the subscription Id
$subscriptionId = 'xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx'

$resourceGroupName ='yangsatest'

$diskName = 'VM1_OsDisk_1_xxxxxxxxxxxx'
$location = 'eastus'

$virtualNetworkName = 'yangsatest-vnet'
$virtualMachineName = 'VM2'

$virtualMachineSize = 'Standard_A1'
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId

$disk =  Get-AzureRmDisk -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -DiskName $diskName

$VirtualMachine = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName $virtualMachineName -VMSize $virtualMachineSize -AvailabilitySetId /subscriptions/xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxx-xxxx8-xxxxxx/resourceGroups/yangsatest/providers/Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets/Myset

#Use the Managed Disk Resource Id to attach it to the virtual machine. Please change the OS type to linux if OS disk has linux OS
$VirtualMachine = Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $VirtualMachine -ManagedDiskId $disk.Id -CreateOption Attach -Windows

$publicIp = New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -Name ($VirtualMachineName.ToLower()+'_ip') -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Location $location -AllocationMethod Dynamic

$vnet = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name $virtualNetworkName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName

$nic = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name ($VirtualMachineName.ToLower()+'_nic') -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Location $location -SubnetId $vnet.Subnets[0].Id -PublicIpAddressId $publicIp.Id

$VirtualMachine = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $VirtualMachine -Id $nic.Id

#Create the virtual machine with Managed Disk
New-AzureRmVM -VM $VirtualMachine -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Location $location
```

----------Update----------
Updating Script to fit Official document :**Change the availability set for a Managed Windows VM**(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/change-availability-set):

```
#set variables
    $rg = "demo-resource-group"
    $vmName = "demo-vm"
    $newAvailSetName = "demo-as"
    $outFile = "C:\temp\outfile.txt"

#Get VM Details
    $OriginalVM = get-azurermvm -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $vmName

    #Output VM details to file
    "VM Name: " | Out-File -FilePath $outFile 
    $OriginalVM.Name | Out-File -FilePath $outFile -Append

    "Extensions: " | Out-File -FilePath $outFile -Append
    $OriginalVM.Extensions | Out-File -FilePath $outFile -Append

    "VMSize: " | Out-File -FilePath $outFile -Append
    $OriginalVM.HardwareProfile.VmSize | Out-File -FilePath $outFile -Append

    "NIC: " | Out-File -FilePath $outFile -Append
    $OriginalVM.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces.Id | Out-File -FilePath $outFile -Append

    "OSType: " | Out-File -FilePath $outFile -Append
    $OriginalVM.StorageProfile.OsDisk.OsType | Out-File -FilePath $outFile -Append

    "OSDisk: " | Out-File -FilePath $outFile -Append
    $OriginalVM.StorageProfile.OsDisk.ManagedDisk.Id| Out-File -FilePath $outFile -Append

    if ($OriginalVM.StorageProfile.DataDisks) {
    "Data Disk(s): " | Out-File -FilePath $outFile -Append
    $OriginalVM.StorageProfile.DataDisks.Id | Out-File -FilePath $outFile -Append
    }

    #Remove the original VM
    Remove-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $vmName
#Create new availability set if it does not exist
    $availSet = Get-AzureRmAvailabilitySet -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $newAvailSetName -ErrorAction Ignore
    if (-Not $availSet) {
    $availset = New-AzureRmAvailabilitySet -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $newAvailSetName -Location $OriginalVM.Location -Managed     -PlatformFaultDomainCount 2    -PlatformUpdateDomainCount 2
    }

    #Create the basic configuration for the replacement VM
    $newVM = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName $OriginalVM.Name -VMSize $OriginalVM.HardwareProfile.VmSize -AvailabilitySetId $availSet.Id
    Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $NewVM -ManagedDisk $OriginalVM.StorageProfile.OsDisk.ManagedDisk.Id   -CreateOption Attach -Windows

    #Add Data Disks
    foreach ($disk in $OriginalVM.StorageProfile.DataDisks ) { 
    Add-AzureRmVMDataDisk -VM $newVM -Name $disk.Name -ManagedDiskId $OriginalVM.StorageProfile.DataDisks.Id -Caching $disk.Caching -Lun $disk.Lun -CreateOption Attach -DiskSizeInGB $disk.DiskSizeGB
    }

    #Add NIC(s)
    foreach ($nic in $OriginalVM.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces.Id) {
        Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $NewVM -Id $nic
    }


    #Create the VM
    New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rg -Location $OriginalVM.Location -VM $NewVM -DisableBginfoExtension
```

Comment: Wayne, if this works for me, I won't be able to thank you enough.. Going to check it out now.

Comment: Hi Wayne, I was about to check out your script when I came across this .ps1 script located here https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Set-Azure-Resource-Manager-f7509ec4/view/Discussions. It appears to work seamlessly, however I don't know if it supports Managed Disk. I have asked the owner of the script, I'm waiting for a reply. Have you come across it?

Comment: Hi, Carltonp,in my test lab, I used Managed disk. You can see it in the script. You can have a try using my script. I do actully move an existing Azure VM with a Managed Disk into an existing Availability Set successfully.

Comment: HI,Carltonp.Did you use the script from this:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/change-availability-set    ? This document is used forUnmanged disk .

Comment: Hi Wayne, that was the script I was using originally. Unfortunately, it was designed for use with unmanaged disks. btw, your script worked like a charm. Cheers mate.

Comment: Hi Wayne, I'm trying to indicate you answered my question, but I don't know where to click 'Answered'

Comment: Hi,Carltonp. I'm glad to hear that my script is helpful.Click "√" which is under  the vote botton.Thank you

Comment: Hi,@Carltonp, can you mark my answer so that it can help other users.Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

for me the problem was that I created a Managed Disk (from Azure Portal) which I selected the wrong OS which caused me this , I re-created managed disk with the right OS and then deployment worked.