# "Changing property 'creationData' is not allowed." Azure Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I'm trying to create a VM from an Azure Snapshot by following the steps outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/scripts/virtual-machines-windows-powershell-sample-create-vm-from-snapshot?toc=%2Fpowershell%2Fmodule%2Ftoc.json).

I have reached the step:

```
$disk = New-AzureRmDisk -Disk $diskConfig -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -DiskName $osDiskName
```

However, when this line is run, the following error is obtained:

```
    New-AzureRmDisk : Changing property 'creationData' is not allowed.
    ErrorCode: PropertyChangeNotAllowed
    ErrorMessage: Changing property 'creationData' is not allowed.
    StatusCode: 409
    ReasonPhrase: Conflict
    OperationID : 85382399-64e8-4547-804d-ef0796301b63
    At line:1 char:9
    + $disk = New-AzureRmDisk -Disk $diskConfig -ResourceGroupName $resourc ...
    +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmDisk], 
    ComputeCloudException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
    Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Automation.NewAzureRmDisk
```

The error seemed similar to [this one posed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45903498/getting-error-changing-property-osdisk-name-is-not-allowed-with-azure-power) however the solution provided does not configure the disk from the snapshot. Any ideas as to what could be causing the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have reproduced your issue on my side, it could be caused by the disk you specified has already been existing in the resource group, because **CreationData** information cannot be changed after the disk has been created, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.compute.models.disk.creationdata?view=azure-dotnet).

At first, the command works fine.

[image]
 After I creating a disk which has the same name in the portal, it gives the same error message of yours.

[image]

Comment: @Christopher If my reply solved your issue, please mark it as answer. Any problem, feel free to tell me.

Comment: Just one follow up question. If I'm creating a VM from a snapshot wouldn't I have to use the same disk which the snapshot relies on? Or would I have to create a new disk?

Comment: @Christopher I am not sure about the limit of the choice of the disk, I recommend you to try it in the portal, it will be clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was getting this error because i was missing one property in `azDiskConfig` command which is

`-CreateOption Empty`.

if you are using image or something it should be `-CreateOption 'FromImage'`

more details on azDiskParams are defined here [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/new-azdisk?view=azps-10.1.0)