# Terraform on Azure, name of VM and managed data disk is not aligned

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am able to ad disk to each of my VM's but their names are not aligned. It creates confusion.

[image]

[image]

Terraform code for creating managed disk and attaching disk to managed disk is below:

```
resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "tf-mdsk-cluster" {
  count                = 5
  name                 = "${var.ax_base_hostname}-${count.index+1}-DATADISK"
  location             = "${azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-cluster-aos.location}"
  resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-cluster-aos.name}"
  storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  create_option        = "Empty"
  disk_size_gb         = "1024"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "tf-vm-cluster-aos" {
  count                 = 5
  name                  = "${var.ax_base_hostname}-${count.index+1}"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-cluster-aos.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-cluster-aos.name}"
  availability_set_id   = "${azurerm_availability_set.tf-as-cluster-aos.id}"
  network_interface_ids = ["${element(azurerm_network_interface.tf-ni-cluster-aos.*.id, count.index+1)}"]
  vm_size               = "${var.ax_vm_size}"


 storage_data_disk {
   name            = "${element(azurerm_managed_disk.tf-mdsk-cluster.*.name, count.index+1)}"
   managed_disk_id = "${element(azurerm_managed_disk.tf-mdsk-cluster.*.id, count.index)}"
   create_option   = "Attach"
   lun             = 0
   disk_size_gb    = "${element(azurerm_managed_disk.tf-mdsk-cluster.*.disk_size_gb, count.index+1)}"
 }
```

Let us go through first iteration:
**NXTPREPAOS-1-DATADISK** is created first and get it gets attached to **NXTPREPAOS-1**, not sure why data disk counter and VM counter are not in sync?

Also, if I have to add another Data Disk of 1 TB to each VM, would my code block like below?

```
 resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "tf-mdsk-1-cluster" {
      count                = 5
      name                 = "${var.ax_base_hostname}-${count.index+1}-DATADISK"
      location             = "${azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-cluster-aos.location}"
      resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-cluster-aos.name}"
      storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
      create_option        = "Empty"
      disk_size_gb         = "1024"
    }

resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "tf-mdsk-2-cluster" {
      count                = 5
      name                 = "${var.ax_base_hostname}-${count.index+1}-DATADISK2"
      location             = "${azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-cluster-aos.location}"
      resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-cluster-aos.name}"
      storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
      create_option        = "Empty"
      disk_size_gb         = "1024"
    }

    resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "tf-vm-cluster-aos" {
      count                 = 5
      name                  = "${var.ax_base_hostname}-${count.index+1}"
      location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-cluster-aos.location}"
      resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-cluster-aos.name}"
      availability_set_id   = "${azurerm_availability_set.tf-as-cluster-aos.id}"
      network_interface_ids = ["${element(azurerm_network_interface.tf-ni-cluster-aos.*.id, count.index+1)}"]
      vm_size               = "${var.ax_vm_size}"


     storage_data_disk {
       name            = "${element(azurerm_managed_disk.tf-mdsk-cluster.*.name, count.index+1)}"
       managed_disk_id = "${element(azurerm_managed_disk.tf-mdsk-cluster.*.id, count.index)}"
       create_option   = "Attach"
       lun             = 0
       disk_size_gb    = "${element(azurerm_managed_disk.tf-mdsk-cluster.*.disk_size_gb, count.index+1)}"
     }

     storage_data_disk {
       name            = "${element(azurerm_managed_disk.tf-mdsk-2-cluster.*.name, count.index+1)}"
       managed_disk_id = "${element(azurerm_managed_disk.tf-mdsk-2-cluster.*.id, count.index)}"
       create_option   = "Attach"
       lun             = 1
       disk_size_gb    = "${element(azurerm_managed_disk.tf-mdsk-2-cluster.*.disk_size_gb, count.index+1)}"
     }
```

Comment: you sure are you not omitting the os_disk property? i think you are

Comment: No, I have not, just to reduce code on here (Stack overflow, I deleted it.) else it complains that I have more code and less text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to be incrementing the `count.index` by 1 when referring to the other resource:

```
name            = "${element(azurerm_managed_disk.tf-mdsk-cluster.*.name, count.index+1)}"
disk_size_gb    = "${element(azurerm_managed_disk.tf-mdsk-cluster.*.disk_size_gb, count.index+1)}"
```

Your `azurerm_virtual_machine` resource should look like this instead:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "tf-vm-cluster-aos" {
  count                 = 5
  name                  = "${var.ax_base_hostname}-${count.index+1}"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-cluster-aos.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-cluster-aos.name}"
  availability_set_id   = "${azurerm_availability_set.tf-as-cluster-aos.id}"
  network_interface_ids = ["${element(azurerm_network_interface.tf-ni-cluster-aos.*.id, count.index+1)}"]
  vm_size               = "${var.ax_vm_size}"


 storage_data_disk {
   name            = "${element(azurerm_managed_disk.tf-mdsk-cluster.*.name, count.index)}"
   managed_disk_id = "${element(azurerm_managed_disk.tf-mdsk-cluster.*.id, count.index)}"
   create_option   = "Attach"
   lun             = 0
   disk_size_gb    = "${element(azurerm_managed_disk.tf-mdsk-cluster.*.disk_size_gb, count.index)}"
 }

 storage_data_disk {
   name            = "${element(azurerm_managed_disk.tf-mdsk-2-cluster.*.name, count.index)}"
   managed_disk_id = "${element(azurerm_managed_disk.tf-mdsk-2-cluster.*.id, count.index)}"
   create_option   = "Attach"
   lun             = 1
   disk_size_gb    = "${element(azurerm_managed_disk.tf-mdsk-2-cluster.*.disk_size_gb, count.index)}"
 }
```

You might also find it preferable to use the [`list[index]` syntax](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#user-list-variables) here too:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "tf-vm-cluster-aos" {
  count                 = 5
  name                  = "${var.ax_base_hostname}-${count.index+1}"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-cluster-aos.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-cluster-aos.name}"
  availability_set_id   = "${azurerm_availability_set.tf-as-cluster-aos.id}"
  network_interface_ids = ["${element(azurerm_network_interface.tf-ni-cluster-aos.*.id, count.index+1)}"]
  vm_size               = "${var.ax_vm_size}"


 storage_data_disk {
   name            = "${element(azurerm_managed_disk.tf-mdsk-cluster.*.name, count.index)}"
   managed_disk_id = "${element(azurerm_managed_disk.tf-mdsk-cluster.*.id, count.index)}"
   create_option   = "Attach"
   lun             = 0
   disk_size_gb    = "${element(azurerm_managed_disk.tf-mdsk-cluster.*.disk_size_gb, count.index)}"
 }

 storage_data_disk {
   name            = "${azurerm_managed_disk.tf-mdsk-2-cluster.*.name[count.index]}"
   managed_disk_id = "${azurerm_managed_disk.tf-mdsk-2-cluster.*.id[count.index]}"
   create_option   = "Attach"
   lun             = 1
   disk_size_gb    = "${azurerm_managed_disk.tf-mdsk-2-cluster.*.disk_size_gb[count.index]}"
 }
```

Comment: I definitely tried the index thing you suggested but it does not work the way it should. 
Example screenshot below

Comment: Looks like I cannot put screenshot in comment.

Comment: i think +1 is not needed there? loops start at 0?

Comment: I definitely tried the index thing you suggested but it does not work the way it should. 
NXTPREPAOS-1 - Disks
-- 
NXTPREPAOS-1-OS-DISK
NXTPREPAOS-2-DATADISK-1
NXTPREPAOS-2-DATADISK-2

Take Vm3:
NXTPREPAOS-3 - Disks
--
NXTPREPAOS-3-OS-DISK
NXTPREPAOS-4-DATADISK-1
NXTPREPAOS-4-DATADISK-2

I'm totally confused how to handle this...

Comment: Yes I thought so as well hence I removed +1 but it errors out. Terraform doco lacks examples, unfortunately so that does not help.

Comment: I went the wrong way, apologies, misread your code first thing this morning. You don't need the index incrementing when referring to the other resource.

Comment: I removed the counter +1 from managed disk id and I get error below:
Error: Error applying plan:
5 error(s) occurred:

Comment: * azurerm_virtual_machine.tf-vm-cluster-aos[1]: 1 error(s) occurred:

* azurerm_virtual_machine.tf-vm-cluster-aos.1: compute.VirtualMachinesClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=<nil> Code="PropertyChangeNotAllowed" Message="Changing property 'dataDisk.name' is not allowed." Target="dataDisk.name"

Comment: So for each VM it complains like the above?

Comment: You can't change the name of the disks so you will need to destroy and reapply. Really the Azure provider should know this and force a new resource on an apply too but I have no real experience with using Terraform with Azure so not sure why that's not already been fixed in the provider.

Comment: I am not changing name. I destroy everything and then create everything from scratch. I'm probably better off to use Ansible to add disks. I dd google and seems issue with Terraform...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45903498/getting-error-changing-property-osdisk-name-is-not-allowed-with-azure-power

Comment: I want infrastructure provisioning by Terraform and Configuration management by Ansible. Terraform doesn't seem to add disk easily. When we add first disk, name is not right, when we add second disk it completely burst out...

Comment: No, it's because you applied with your incorrect code first time and then tried to apply again causing Terraform to try to update the disk. You should destroy everything and apply from scratch with the fixed code. If that throws a different error then you should raise a separate question showing the code you've used there and the exact error you get.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188704/discussion-between-learner-and-ydaetskcor).

Comment: We do not have to offset disk size as well. Offsetting twice causes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I find that referencing the direct name given to the virtual machine provides a more consistent result. allowing things to keep in sync.

```
resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "tf-mdsk-2-cluster" {
      count                = 5
      name                 = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.tf-vm-cluster-aos[count.index].name}-DATADISK2"
      location             = "${azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-cluster-aos.location}"
      resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-cluster-aos.name}"
      storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
      create_option        = "Empty"
      disk_size_gb         = "1024"
    }
```